How to validate if indirect ACR still valid when Direct ACR has moved
After some guidance / Advice
Our Org is using ACR and we have enabled the setting "delete the relationship between the contact and the previous primary account"
Which basically means if the contact primary account changes from account "A" to Account "B" it doesn't create an an indirect relationship.
My question is this, if a contact has 3 indirect relationships and a user moves the primary contact from account "A" to account "B", how do do you manage the indirect relationships ?
I.e. When the User moves the primary relationship, do you have something to present to the user to say ;

Are these indirect relationships still valid ?

At the moment the ACR is not actively being kept up to date, and i am trying to find clever ways to ask the user to validate the indirect relationships when the primary relationship changes
Looking forward to your assistance
Masond3
